# Getting more current through an LED array

Tags: arduino-uno, led, current

I have an Arduino Uno controlling an array of 24 LEDs ([datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/427/vlmu3500xxx120-968628.pdf)).  I understand these LEDs are ultraviolet and have a forward current of 0.5A.  My power source (12V 2A) is wired to a switch which is then wired to the LED array and Arduino.  I should probably use a 12V 4A power source but was worried if too much current would go to the Arduino.  As per my attached diagram, the Arduino and LED array are in parallel.  I would like to get more current through my LEDs to increase their brightness.  What would be the best way to do this?

Updated: I tried adding a 100 Ohm resistor (where R11 is located) but the Arduino wasn't drawing enough power to turn on my LCD.  And then I tried a 1 Ohm resistor instead but the resistor burned out.  Unfortunately, I threw out the resistor and don't have a picture of it.  I believe the correct value should be ~47 Ohm so I have added that resistance as R11.  However, I haven't tested it yet as I want to make sure it's correct.  (12V - 6V) = 130mA * R >>> R = 46.15 Ohm.  I used a voltage drop of 6V so that at least 5V is still going into the Arduino (12V - 6V = 6V which is greater than 5V).  I measured the current through a multimeter to be 130mA.

[image: Updated schematic with resistor values]

Comment: This diagram is really messy. Also, I'm going to vote to migrate this question to the Electrical Engineering StackExchange because that is probably a better place to ask this.

Comment: Please edit your question and/or the  diagram to include values for R1–R9.  (R1-R8 have a lot to do with how much current flows.) Also edit your question to indicate whether you know the spec sheet is for a UV LED that does not produce visible light and it is specified for 1/2 amp forward current so that 8 strands of LEDs would take 4 amps, which a 12 V, 2 A supply can't handle.  Also say where the 1Ω resistor that burned out was located and add a picture of the burned out resistor

Comment: @Padraig, regardless if my answer works for you - please do as James Waldby requests and reword your question so that more people can make use of this exchange of information.

Answer (score 1):

The current a bipolar transistor configured as a [common emitter amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter) will allow from its collector to its emitter is equal to its [beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Transistor_parameters:_alpha_.28.CE.B1.29_and_beta_.28.CE.B2.29) time the base to emitter current.

A beta of 100 is common for many transistors. Assuming this information is close enough to your transistor, we can choose a base series resistance suitable for the collector to emitter current desired.

For example if you were using a 5 volt microprocessor and the voltage drop across the base to emitter was the usual 0.7 volts for silicon semiconductors and you had a base series resistor of 10Kohms:

```
V = I * R
V = 5 - 0.7 = 4.3 volts
R = 10000 ohms
I = 4.3/10000 = 0.43mA
I(ce) = Beta * 0.43mA
I(ce) = 100 * 0.43mA = 43mA
```

You could pass up to 43mA from the collector to the emitter.  If that is not enough,you can lowered the base resistor to 1Kohms:

```
R = 1000 ohms
I = 4.3/1000 = 4.3mA
I(ce) = Beta * 4.3mA
I(ce) = 100 * 4.3mA = 430mA
```

And increase the current to 430mA.  You still need to verify that the processor can supply the current to control the transistor (4.3mA as calculated above) as well as pick a transistor of sufficient capacity to handle the load.

If a beta of about 100 is not enough, consider using a [Darlington transistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor) arrangement. This type of "2 transistor" device has a gain of the product of each individual transistor's beta.  So, it is common for such a device to have a beta of 10000!  Using this device, you can use a much larger base resistor and still be able to switch more current.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried adding a 100 Ohm resistor (where R11 is located) but the Arduino wasn't drawing enough power to turn on my LCD.

You should not have a resistor in the Arduino's supply line at all.

> And then I tried a 1 Ohm resistor instead but the resistor burned out.

If you really wanted to have one to share the heat load of the on-board regulator, it would need to be a `power resistor` of appropriate wattage rating.

> I believe the correct value should be ~47 Ohm so I have added that resistance as R11...I used a voltage drop of 6V so that at least 5V is still going into the Arduino (12V - 6V = 6V which is greater than 5V). I measured the current through a multimeter to be 130mA.

This is incorrect.

The Arduino's regulator needs something like 7 volts input to operate correctly.

The power drawn by the Arduino will not be fixed, it will depend on what it is doing, what I/Os are exerted against what loads, and other things like the LCD you apparently have.

Likely, if you want to use a power resistor you should design it to drop no more than half of the difference between the supply voltage and the regulator dropout voltage, under conditions of *maximum* load.  A fixed power resistor cannot be used to *replace* the *variable power resistor* that is a linear regulator; at most it can be used to offset some of the *fixed* part of the resistance and resulting thermal load.  But you still have to leave all of the variable part plus a healthy margin for the regulator to handle, or it won't be able to regulate.

It would be simpler to just put a heatsink on the regulator.